# Add a numpy array to the beginning or end of each element of another array

Tags: python, numpy, stack

I have an array of arrays:

```
x = array([array([[1, 2],
   [3, 4]]),
   array([[22,  4],
   [ 9, 10],
   [ 3,  2]])], dtype=object)
```

And i have a list of arrays with same length like:

```
xa = [array([11, 22]), array([33, 44])]
```

I would like to add, in pure numpy, each element of xa to the end or beginning of x, as follows:

- In the end:

  ```
  result = array([array([[ 1,  2],
   [ 3,  4],
   [11, 22]]),
   array([[22,  4],
   [ 9, 10],
   [ 3,  2],
   [33, 44]])], dtype=object)
  ```
- In the beginning:

  ```
  result = array([array([[11, 22],
   [ 1,  2],
   [ 3,  4]]),
   array([[33, 44],
   [22,  4],
   [ 9, 10],
   [ 3,  2]])], dtype=object)
  ```

***Numpy version = 1.9.3**

Comment: 'pure numpy' only works for numeric dtype arrays.  Object dtype arrays have to be handled like lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you imported numpy like that:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import array
```

(1) not biutifully but this would work:

```
result = array([np.vstack((x[0], xa[0])), np.vstack((x[1], xa[1]))])
```

or respectively:

```
result = array([np.vstack((xa[0], x[0])), np.vstack((xa[1], x[1]))])
```

(2) better with flexible lengths of the two arrays:

```
result = array([np.vstack((x[i], xa[i])) for i in range(len(x))])
result = array([np.vstack((xa[i], x[i])) for i in range(len(x))])
```

(3) a bit more pythonic way of handling this:

```
result = array([np.vstack((x_i, xa_i)) for (x_i, xa_i) in zip(x, xa)])
result = array([np.vstack((xa_i, x_i)) for (x_i, xa_i) in zip(x, xa)])
```